# How to implement TryFrom for a generic type in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a `Foo<T>` type, which I want to be convertible from `T`, but the conversion might return an error, so I use `TryFrom` instead of `From`:

```rust
struct A<T> {
    x: T,
}

struct MyError;

impl<T> TryFrom<T> for A<T> {
    type Error = MyError;
    
    fn try_from(x: T) -> Result<Self, MyError> { Ok(A{x}) }
}
```

For this code, I get the following error message:

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `TryFrom<_>` for type `A<_>`
 --> src/main.rs:7:1
  |
7 | impl<T> TryFrom<T> for A<T> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: conflicting implementation in crate `core`:
          - impl<T, U> TryFrom<U> for T
            where U: Into<T>;

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0119`.
```

If I replace `TryFrom` with `From`, it works, but it's not good for my use case because I need error handling.

I cannot understand the error here. It says that I cannot implement `TryFrom` from `U` to `T`, because there is also a `Into` implementation for the same conversion. I have multiple questions that I don't understand:

- Where is the `Into` implementation that causes the conflict? I didn't write any.
- If there were an `Into` implementation that causes the conflict, wouldn't that also conflict with a `From` implementaiton?

Comment: You may need to pin down your `T` more specifically with a `where` to avoid capturing your own `A<T>` type recursively. You get an automatic `Into<X>` for any given `X`. It doesn't do anything but means that `X` is convertible to itself, obviously.

Comment: In my real use case, T is specifically a trait from an external library.

Comment: As tadman said, you probably want to use `where`.

When you say `for A<T>` it means "for type A with generic type T", but if T is a trait, the syntax is: `for A where A: T`.

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the `Into` implementation that causes the conflict? I didn't write any.

The compiler doesn't mean such implementation *exists*, it means such implementation *could be written* in any downstream crate (a dependency of your crate) - `impl Into<A<SomeDownstreamType>> for SomeDownstreamType`. Because such implementation could be written, you are prohibited from having your impl due to the orphan rules as they will conflict.

> If there were an `Into` implementation that causes the conflict, wouldn't that also conflict with a `From` implementaiton?

I'm not sure I understand what you mean. If both `From` and `Into` impls will be written, yes, they will conflict, but one can be written without problem.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. The above implementation works with `From` but not with `TryFrom`.